# Multilanguage with Laravel

Tags: laravel, multilingual

I would like to offer a finished project in other languages. The user should be able to choose himself which language he would like to use. There should be a language file for each language in which all texts to be translated are stored. I do not mean user content, but texts on the website, buttons, agb's, privacy ...

What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization) create a folder with language translations. Make folder for each language.